# Manusear dados Entity Framework Usando C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Tenho uma conexão com o banco  de dados usando o Entity Framework.

O código é o seguinte

```
public IQueryable Empresas()
{
    int idUser = Int32.Parse(self.IdUser());
    var res = from s in db.EmpresaUsuario
              join c in db.Empresas on s.EmpSequencia equals c.EmpSequencia
              where s.UsuSequencia == idUser
              select c;
    return res;
}
```

Como faço para ler o retorno do banco de dados usando este método?

Não compreendi se a *query* já foi submetida ou  se tenho que submeter ao banco de dados e como  faço para ler o retorno